# Fasting in Nissan for epidemic

Tags: minhag, fast-days, choleh-sick, nissan

In general we refrain from observing fast days during the month of Nissan ([S"A O"C 429:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.429.2?with=all&lang=bi)). There are some exceptions, like a *taanis chalom*.

For a communal distress such as a deadly epidemic a communal fast day should be declared ([S"A O"C 576:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.576.5?with=all&lang=bi)).

Can such a fast day be declared during Nissan?

Comment: Mordechai certainly thought you could (Esther 4:16)

Comment: See Shulchan Aruch OC 572 for the days that you legally can't declare a public fast day. Your source is mentioning a custom not to during nissan. The question becomes if the need to fast and cry out to God in a time of distress (a biblical commandment) outweighs said custom.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/107069/11532